# Enlarge sticky notes font-size in Windows10 when ctrl+shift+greaterthansign doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, fonts

How should one enlarge sticky notes font-size in **Windows10 home (Creator's update)** when `ctrl+shift+greaterthansign` doesn't work and there is no option to so from the `...` symbol in the top bar of the sticky note window?

`ctrl+shift+plus(+)` also didn't work.

Comment: [Sticky Notes in Windows 10: Tips to use, save, format, backup, restore](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/tips-to-use-format-sticky-notes-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an awesome workaround third party solution to enlarge sticky notes font-size and use still be able to use stickies in Windows 10, which can be downloaded for free. It is called "Stickies" from Zhorn Software, which uses either "Control + moving mouse wheel" or "Control + the Plus sign" to easily make font size larger.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.